# MVC [Authorize] Extension to only check an 'enabled' bit flag

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-membership

I'm using EF code first and ASP.NET MVC 4. My users will sign in to the site exclusively with OAuth providers, not native accounts. I've got it working no problem, with a Users table as part of my standard model and the webpages_OAuthMembership holding the OAuth data. I've added an 'Enabled' bit field on my Users table so that, while the site is still in 'alpha', users will not have access to the site unless I approve it. So users can create OAuth accounts but I want to isolate specific controllers using annotation to prevent their use. For instance, I have a 'widgets' controller. right now its set to [Authorize] so that users must be logged in. But I want my own custom annotation, [Approved] or [Enabled], so that even logged in, users cannot proceed unless I've flipped that bit to 'on' in the users table. While I could write my own helper method and inject it manually, I'd rather use annotations as it's easier to roll out and remove once the site is live.

In the future, if the website ever charged money, I'd love to swap out [Enabled] to check to see if the user is up to date, payments wise. So I feel like annotation is the right way to go, just not sure 100% how to do it, and that there's not already a membership faculty out there for this that I'm ignorant of.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you simply add a check for the Enabled bit when you validate their login?  Then you can prevent non-enabled users from logging in completely (not sure why you would want them to log in but not be able to access any pages.. kind of silly).

Alternatively, you can simply use Roles for this.  Add users to an "Enabled" role, and then configure your pages to only allow access from that role.  Seems a lot easier than rolling your own for some reason.

Comment: Not that they can't access 'any' pages, but they are restricted from accessing some. If you think of a loyal customer whose credit card has been cancelled, they might have missed payment. you want them to be able to log in and manipulate their account, but not access parts of the site they should be paying for. It's not unreasonable. I could certainly add a Role; but before I went down that route wanted to make sure.

Comment: @Richthofen - Using roles would be simple, not require any special code, other than the configuration, there's literally no reason you would want to do anything else.  If their membership lapses, you just remove the "ValidMember" role or whatever, and they can't access the areas protected by a ValidMember role.

Comment: Roles are cool, I'm definitely considering it. One more question: Are roles appropriate outside of the ASP.NET MVC framework? For instance, I plan on also releasing an API. the API will authenticate against the users table as well. Can Roles be extended, to say, a web service method?

Comment: @Richthofen - Roles are just a mechanism of the Membership subsystem.  The correct question is to ask if you can use membership in a web service, and the answer to that is yes, which means you can use roles.

Comment: Upvoted and marked as answer. I need to move my membership declaration stuff into a class library instead of happening in the website, but other than that, I will proceed w/ Roles.

Comment: @Richthofen - you still have to configure membership at the web site level, although you can configure it the same.  If you're using custom membership then you can delegate from a membership wrapper to a common implementation.